# Error: Variable-sized object may not be initialized. I don't get why

Tags: c, compiler-errors, variable-length-array

I was trying to do this exercise code in initialization of arrays and I keep getting the error that's stated in the title. Researching online I've seen that defining `SIZE` as constant should do the job but it's not working for me. The thing is I've copied this code from my professor and it ran fine for him. Can you help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const int SIZE = 5; 
    
    int grades[SIZE] = {78, 67, 92, 83, 88};
    double sum;
    int i;
    
[...]

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Variable sized arrays cannot be initialized in the C language.

You need to initialize them manually

```
int main(void) {
    int SIZE = 5; 
    int grades[SIZE];
   
    memcpy(grades, (int[]){78, 67, 92, 83, 88}, sizeof(grades));
```

Your incompetent professor was actually using C++ compiler - but it is a different language and C++ compiler must not be used to compile C code

Comment: In fact, it can be the - equally bad - clang compiler, which converts this to static array (`warning: variable length array folded to constant array as an extension [-Wgnu-folding-constant]`) silently by default...

Comment: https://reviews.llvm.org/D89523