# How does this video on C avoid *Error: Variable-sized object may not be initialized* during compilation?

Tags: arrays, c, gcc, clang

*** EDIT - I know it is a long post and I know I have used some 'interesting' language choices. And, I'm choosing to believe the three answers I've had so far were made with good intent - for that I thank you. But, I really must insist, if you are not willing to read the whole post thoroughly or if you don't understand what it is I am actually asking, please save both our time and refrain from posting. ***

I have been searching for an answer to *exactly* the same question posed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66834839/error-variable-sized-object-may-not-be-initialized-i-dont-get-why?noredirect=1) - same online course, same lecturer; I recognise the code from the video.

I quickly found solutions in the form of #define and using an enum, but that still didn't really solve how the lecturer got his code to compile; and, I would like to actually comprehend, not just make it work so, I tried to dig deeper.

The professor in question doesn't ever actually show the code compilation, it's always a "here's one I compiled earlier" scenario - so I had included the possibility the error was in that unseen stage as indicated by the two answers on the page: he may well have been using g++ or clang.

However, my search was most circuitous, leading me hither and tither across the net, and in my quest, before I came across the above linked answers and amongst other things I came across this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rww_OHQOmbs) where at around the 9 minute mark he compiles this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int ARRAY_LENGTH = 5;

void printarray(int myarray[ARRAY_LENGTH]) {

    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++){
        printf("%i, ", myarray[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}


int main (int argc, char **argv){   

    int a[ARRAY_LENGTH] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int b[ARRAY_LENGTH] = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};

    int *p = malloc(sizeof(int) * 567);

    printarray(a);
    printarray(b);
    printarray(p);

    free(p);

}
```

He uses a makefile that runs gcc with the -g -Wall flags and is on a mac (I think, please correct me if I am wrong). The internet tells me clang is the default compiler on macs, so maybe this is something to do with it (although I have no idea why that would be), but trying this code with g++ gives `error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]`.

I would just like to understand what is actually going on. Not that *consts in C aren't actually constant, more like read-only; use #define/enum*. I've read that (probably on here), I've understood it, I've re-written my code and successfully compiled using both methodologies. I've even compiled using *const* by separating the declaration and assignment. And, at this point, it's not about how the original lecturer compiled his code anymore - I've tested g++ it definitely works, and, if I'd have found that answer earlier I would probably be happily satisfied now with no further questions.

But, I didn't. And, none of what I've found explains how the code from the video compiled and ran (or, why multiple people think this is good practice C coding that should be shared as educational material, but that seems a secondary digression). Maybe its a simple typo, but I've checked and re-checked and I simply cannot find it. Hopefully, someone will be able to adequately put an end to the mystery that plagues me.

Thank you for your time in reading, it seems a bit long but I was trying to be thorough and avoid the all too common initial question-answer ping-pong. No doubt I have still neglected something of the utmost import - c'est la vie.

Comment: C and C++ are 2 different languages. Trying to compile C code with a C++ compiler will often not work

Comment: In this case `int *p = malloc(sizeof(int) * 567);` is valid C code, but not valid in C++, which is why `g++` gives you the error

Comment: f you are sticking with the [tag:c] tag: The initialization error is because you are trying to initialize a VLA (_variable length array_). Use a constant expression, like `enum { ARRAY_LENGTH = 5 };` or `#define ARRAY_LENGTH 5,` and you can then do `int a[ARRAY_LENGTH] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};` - The array will no longer be a VLA but it'll compile.

Comment: FYI: The reason why this code compiles for the author of that video is because he's using Clang which seems to have the `gnu-folding-constant` extension turned on by default https://godbolt.org/z/PPvfGos57

Comment: @UnholySheep looking at the video it seems that the author is using gcc.

Comment: @anastaciu It's clearly recorded on macOS where by default `gcc` is an alias for `clang`. Either that or the author is using some strange version of GCC which performs non-standard constant folding

Comment: @UnholySheep, the alias situation would explain it, but for the fact that no warning is shown, `-Wall` flag is being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a result of *constant folding* in the clang compiler.

The instructor is compiling the program on a Mac, and on that platform "gcc" is an alias for "clang".  While gcc does not perform this folding for a VLA, clang does.

From the clang documentation (version 10):

> Differences between all c* and gnu* modes:
>
> - c* modes define `__STRICT_ANSI__`.
> - Target-specific defines not prefixed by underscores, like “linux”, are defined in gnu* modes.
> - Trigraphs default to being off in gnu* modes; they can be enabled by the -trigraphs option.
> - The parser recognizes `asm` and `typeof` as keywords in gnu* modes; the variants `__asm__` and `__typeof__` are recognized in all modes.
> - The Apple “blocks” extension is recognized by default in gnu* modes on some platforms; it can be enabled in any mode with the `-fblocks`
>   option.
> - **Arrays that are VLA’s according to the standard, but which can be constant folded by the frontend are treated as fixed size arrays. This
>   occurs for things like `int X[(1, 2)];`, which is technically a VLA. c *
>   modes are strictly compliant and treat these as VLAs.**

Comment: It seems that starting with version 12 Clang does emit a warning about this, but presumably the version that ships with macOS is older